# Getting all values cointaining searched element using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I'm working on an Android app that should do some work on HTML - finding part of an HTML body, getting attributes and the last one - getting values containing searched element. So I did point one and two but I can't handle that last third part. I've been trying to achieve that using something like this:

```
public List<String> getSpecificValue(String searchedElement){
         //builder containing my html code...
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(builder.toString());
    Elements elements = doc.getAllElements();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Element e : elements){
        if(e.text().toLowerCase().contains(searchedElement.toLowerCase())){
            list.add(e.text());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

So the example for stackoverflow.com and searched element i.e "ack" my code should return every value on that site which contains that 3 letters. Any help and suggestions?

Comment: What happens with the code you have now?

Comment: Hey David, thanks for reply, my code in that form was producing every element from random mobile connection(i.e connecting to google.com suggested to download their app)? Actually solved my problem by splitting (" ") every element in my list. It seems it was cutting whole parts of code rather than single word. I just created loop that was splitting every element, added it to the list and finally using `String.contains(string)` I got my every value containing searched word. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Elements elements = doc.getElementsContainingText("mySearchText")
```

to find elements that contain the specified string